# Typo3, DEB.SURY and TFS build pipeline: problem with helhum/typo3-console and PHP version

Tags: php, tfs, debian, typo3, typo3-9.x

We are currently encountering a problem with the *helhum/typo3-console* extension that we can’t figure out.

We are trying to set up a workflow for our *TYPO3* developments using *Microsoft TFS* (*Azure DevOps - On premise*) with a build agent installed on a *Debian* machine (*Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 - PHP 7.0.33*). However, for some reasons, our system administrators decided to use *DEB.SURY* (https://deb.sury.org/) to manage multiple versions of *PHP* on the same machine. The build pipeline we are working on is dedicated to a *TYPO3 9.5* installation using *PHP 7.3*.

We noticed the following thing: because (or at least, it seems) the file "*./vendor/helhum/typo3-console/typo3cms*" contains the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env php`, it always throws an error when we run a command like `typo3cms install:generatepackagestates` because it uses the version of PHP delivered by the OS and not the one we specified. So, if we do something like so:

```
php7.3 typo3cms install:generatepackagestates
```

...it will throw an error because it will not use *PHP 7.3*, but *PHP 7.0.33*.

So, we created a copy of the file, placed it at the root of our directory, and removed the first line. In that file, we also changed the line calling the *typo3-console.php* file by `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Scripts/typo3-console.php';`.

We also set the following things on the fly in our build environment:

```
export TYPO3_PATH_ROOT="./public"
export TYPO3_PATH_WEB="./public"
```

Now can do something like this in our build pipeline:

```
php7.3 ./typo3cms-custom.php install:generatepackagestates
```

This is almost great! However, we are now encountering the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/../../../../Configuration/ComposerPackagesCommands.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/CommandConfiguration.php on line 169
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/../../../../Configuration/ComposerPackagesCommands.php' (include_path='/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/nimut/testing-framework/.Build/vendor/pear/http_request2:/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/nimut/testing-framework/.Build/vendor/pear/net_url2:.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/CommandConfiguration.php on line 169
```

We spent hours trying to understand why, but, to be honest we cannot figure it out. Can someone give us a little help on this or just a little hint? It would be much appreciated. Has anyone encountered such a problem or behaviour?

Many thanks in advance.

Best regards,

**EDIT 1**

We noticed that the file *Configuration/ComposerPackagesCommands.php* that is generated through the *PopulateCommandConfiguration.php* file is not present in the vendor directory on our build machine.

We managed to regenerate the missing file *Configuration/ComposerPackagesCommands.php*, however, we not get other errors.

If we run *install:generatepackagestates*

```
    [ RuntimeException ]                                            
Cannot set an alias map as the alias loader is not registered!  

Exception code: 1439228111

Exception trace:
#0 ()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/typo3/class-alias-loader/src/ClassAliasMap.php:60
#1 TYPO3\ClassAliasLoader\ClassAliasMap::addAliasMap()
typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/ClassLoadingInformation.php:160
#2 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\ClassLoadingInformation::registerTransientClassLoadingInformationForPackage()
typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Package/PackageManager.php:636
#3 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\PackageManager->registerTransientClassLoadingInformationForPackage()
typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Package/PackageManager.php:600
#4 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\PackageManager->activatePackage()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Install/PackageStatesGenerator.php:60
#5 Helhum\Typo3Console\Install\PackageStatesGenerator->generate()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Command/Install/InstallGeneratePackageStatesCommand.php:124
#6 Helhum\Typo3Console\Command\Install\InstallGeneratePackageStatesCommand->execute()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
#7 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1001
#8 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/Symfony/Application.php:169
#9 Helhum\Typo3Console\Mvc\Cli\Symfony\Application->doRunCommand()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:271
#10 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:147
#11 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Core/Kernel.php:148
#12 Helhum\Typo3Console\Core\Kernel->handle()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Scripts/typo3-console.php:16
#13 {closure}()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Scripts/typo3-console.php:18
#14 require()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/typo3cms-custom.php:17
```

If we run *install:fixfolderstructure*

```
    [ TYPO3\CMS\Install\FolderStructure\Exception\InvalidArgumentException ]  
Root node expects absolute path as name                                   

Exception code: 1366141329

Exception trace:
#0 ()
typo3/sysext/install/Classes/FolderStructure/RootNode.php:46
#1 TYPO3\CMS\Install\FolderStructure\RootNode->__construct()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Install/FolderStructure/ExtensionFactory.php:59
#2 Helhum\Typo3Console\Install\FolderStructure\ExtensionFactory->getStructure()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Command/Install/InstallFixFolderStructureCommand.php:77
#3 Helhum\Typo3Console\Command\Install\InstallFixFolderStructureCommand->execute()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
#4 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1001
#5 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Mvc/Cli/Symfony/Application.php:169
#6 Helhum\Typo3Console\Mvc\Cli\Symfony\Application->doRunCommand()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:271
#7 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:147
#8 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Classes/Console/Core/Kernel.php:148
#9 Helhum\Typo3Console\Core\Kernel->handle()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Scripts/typo3-console.php:16
#10 {closure}()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/vendor/helhum/typo3-console/Scripts/typo3-console.php:18
#11 require()
/opt/vstsagent/_work/5/s/typo3cms-custom.php:17
```

As we understand it, the problem comes from the various scripts that need to be executed to finish a *TYPO3* installation (or update), because, even if we specify to execute commands with a specific version of *PHP*, at some point, the version delivred by the OS is used. For now, it seems that our various workarounds don't work very well.

**EDIT 2**

We also tried the following things without success:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/php7.3:$PATH
php typo3cms install:generatepackagestates
# FAILURE

alias php='/usr/bin/php7.3'
php typo3cms install:generatepackagestates
# FAILURE

alias php=php7.3
php typo3cms install:generatepackagestates
# FAILURE

set PATH="/usr/bin/php7.3:$PATH"
php typo3cms install:generatepackagestates
# FAILURE

env PATH="/usr/bin/php7.3:$PATH" php typo3cms install:generatepackagestates
# FAILURE
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't use the version of *PHP* we specified. What is interesting, is we can do the following thing directly on the build machine:

```
$ alias php=php7.3
$ alias 
alias php='php7.3'
$ php -v
PHP 7.3...
```

However, it doesn't produce the same result if we do the same thing in the build pipeline. We have:

```
$ alias php=php7.3
$ alias 
alias php='php7.3'
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.33...
```

**EDIT 3 (and solution ?)**

After hours, we finally managed to make things work (it seems) like so:

```
$ shopt -s expand_aliases
$ alias php=php7.3
alias php='php7.3'
$ php -v
PHP 7.3...

$ php ./typo3cms-custom.php install:fixfolderstructure
$ php ./typo3cms-custom.php install:generatepackagestates
$ php ./typo3cms-custom.php cache:flush --files-only
$ php ./composer.phar dump-autoload -o --no-scripts
```

Like so, TYPO3 scripts work and don't output any errors. However, when we do `composer install` the step before, we have to let the post scripts installation failed to get the file *Configuration/ComposerPackagesCommands.php*, otherwise, this last one is missing. This is not really clean, but we don't have a better solution for now.

If anyone has a better suggestion...

Comment: What's the result if you manually build directly on the build agent machine instead through TFS? Did you also get similar warning/error. This looks like an environment related issue. Not TFS side configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. We also tried to build the project manually on the build machine, using the same steps, but the result is the same.